# What are valid values for contentType attribute in computed field like xs:GoogleSearch?

Tags: xpages

From this [tweet by Paul Hannan](https://twitter.com/pdhannan/status/337232701763489792) I learned that you can set `contentType` to `xs:GoogleSearch` and the string generated becomes a link to search to Google. So for example if code is:

```
<xp:text id="c1" value="XPages" contentType="xs:GoogleSearch">
```

The generated HTML is something like this with a Google search link for term "XPages"

```
<span id="view:_id1:c1" class="xspTextComputedField">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=XPages" target="_blank">XPages</a>
</span>
```

Domino Designer (8.5.3) only shows two options of `html` and `text`, but this worked in my case. My question is, are there any other valid values which can be used for `contentType` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

This should tell you the answer your looking for on any given version.

```
List localList = ((ApplicationEx)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()).findServices("com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ContentTypeRenderer");
```

These are the ones I see on 8.5.3

```
xs:lc.vcard|Profiles VCard
xs:lc.vcardi|Profiles VCard Inline
xs:st.livename|IBM Sametime Live Names
twitterContent
xs:GoogleSearch|Google Search
```

Comment: I guess this depends on the version of the Extension Library

Comment: Very well could be, they are extlib classes, basically they are anything that implements com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ContentTypeRenderer

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: So this is dependent on Extension Library? I have extension library installed.

Comment: @TobySamples: The code did not work for. It always returns an empty `List`. Also the other values of `contentType` like `xs:lc.vcard` also did not work for me. Is there something that I have missed?

Comment: @TobySamples: As far I can see, yes. In ND9 there is only Google Search available. The SBT contains the twitter / vCard / Sametime renderer

Comment: @Naveen Are you running the code on the server or just on localhost?

Comment: @TobySamples: I am running the code on my localhost. I have extension library installed on my local machine.

Comment: if you install extlibx you get these options